# Difference between Timestamp is 15 minutes

Tags: sql, timestamp, hive

This is the CREATED_TIME `2012-07-17 00:00:22` and this is the Corresponding Timestamp `1342508427000`. Here timestamp is `5 seconds` more than the `CREATED_TIME`. I need to see below scenario

Currently I have a query, in which I am joining on created_time and timestamp like this-

```
ON (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(testingtable1.created_time) = (prod_and_ts.timestamps / 1000))
```

So in above case, it will not match as timestamp is 5 seconds more than created_time. But I need if the difference between either of the two is within 15 minutes then I need to match it.

So I wrote the below JOIN query- I am not sure whether this is the right way to do it or not?

```
ON ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(testingtable1.created_time) - (prod_and_ts.timestamps / 1000)) / 60* 1000 <= 15)
```

How I can do the above case if difference between timestamps is within 15 minutes then data will get matched by the above `ON clause`

Comment: Yes . . . I would put the 60 on the other side (xxx/1000 > 15*60) just because I think that is a bit clearer.

Comment: Why you have greater than sign `>`. It should be less than sign `<` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer the (specifically designed for this purpose!) [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) instead of doing al these kinds of calculations with timestamps. You wouldn't believe how much trouble this can cause. Make sure you read and understand [this](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time) and [this](http://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time-wisdom)

Comment: I am working with Hive first of all. So that is the reason i need to do it like this.

Comment: @rjchar It would've been handy if you had mentioned that in your question in the first place. Nevertheless, I am not familiar with Hive but my point still remains. If Hive has date/time functions: use them! (edit: [it does have date/time functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) but they seem pretty limited) I cannot stress enough that this will, sooner or later, come back to bite you in the ass. Is not a timezone the problem then it will be DST transitions or a leap second or ... you name it. Read the articles I linked to.

Comment: On a sidenote: I retagged your question to include `hive` ;-)